# Method to restore just one folder from a CHROME Bookmarks backup?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, restore

I am familiar with Backup and Restore of all Bookmarks in CHROME. My issue is did not notice a very involved single folder is gone. And now months worth of additional cleanup and additions to current Bookmarks will be regressed if I go to an old complete backup just for this folder.

I create on a weekly basis a backup of the current Bookmarks. This folder is in a January backup: bookmarks_1_30_14 | Type = Chrome HTML Document

Any way to copy just this folder from the backup into the current Bookmarks CHROME is using?

BJEvS

Comment: I got my answer by a bit of thought. I ran the Bookmarks IMPORT. Opened the imported folder that is put at the bottom of the Bookmarks Bar list. The folder is named "Imported". Opened it, selected my missing folder, put it back where it belonged in my Bookmarks, deleted the balance of the imported folder named "Imported", and ran an EXPORT from Bookmarks to be sure I had a saved copy with all back to normal.  BJEvS

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of [Iron Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/iron_portable) or Chromium (Depends on your OS)

Import your old bookmarks into it, and open bookmarks manager.

Highlight and copy the folder of bookmarks that you want.
[image]

Open chrome's bookmarks manager, and paste that folder where you want it to go.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply G Koe. But I found a way myself before I read your reply. My way does not require a software download.

Comment: It would have been nicer of you to share the method instead of just shaming the person who tried to help you.